# How to change variables` type in R dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset, which contains character variables, some variables are characters only, but some has only numbers and I want to change them in numeric. How can I do it with base functions?

```
test_data <- as.data.frame(list(
    V1 = c("-0.2372", "0.5231", "0.039", "1.618", "-1.0774"), 
    V2 = c("0.59", "0.7619", "1.7421", "-0.8037", "0.7327"), 
    V3 = c("0.3196", "0.5639", "-0.289", "-0.0822", "0.176"), 
    V4 = c("-1.2442", "0.2814", "-0.924", "0.9123", "-0.4972"), 
    V5 = c("ST 123E", "LD 34", "ST 123E", "ST 123E", "ST 123E")))

str(test_data)
```

Comment: test.data[] <- lapply(test.data, type.convert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test_data[,!sapply(test_data, function(x) all(grepl("[A-z]", x)))] <- lapply(test_data[,!sapply(test_data, function(x) all(grepl("[A-z]", as.character(x))))], as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
test_data <- cbind(
  sapply(test_data[1:4], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))),
  test_data[5])

test_data
#        V1      V2      V3      V4      V5
# 1 -0.2372  0.5900  0.3196 -1.2442 ST 123E
# 2  0.5231  0.7619  0.5639  0.2814   LD 34
# 3  0.0390  1.7421 -0.2890 -0.9240 ST 123E
# 4  1.6180 -0.8037 -0.0822  0.9123 ST 123E
# 5 -1.0774  0.7327  0.1760 -0.4972 ST 123E

str(test_data)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  5 variables:
#   $ V1: num  -0.237 0.523 0.039 1.618 -1.077
# $ V2: num  0.59 0.762 1.742 -0.804 0.733
# $ V3: num  0.3196 0.5639 -0.289 -0.0822 0.176
# $ V4: num  -1.244 0.281 -0.924 0.912 -0.497
# $ V5: Factor w/ 2 levels "LD 34","ST 123E": 2 1 2 2 2
```

Comment: V5 have to save character type

Comment: I've corrected my code - hope this works for you now.

Comment: Very good -- and in that case it is customary to 'accept an answer' (click on the check mark you see next to it) as well as to 'upvote' it (click on the upward-facing triangle). You can vote on any question, you can accept only questions you asked.

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
myfun <- function(I) {
        if (any(grepl("[a-zA-Z]", I))) {  # does column contain characters?
            return(I)  # if yes, return column as factor
        } else {
            return(as.double(I))  # if no, return as double
        }
    }

df <- Reduce("data.frame", lapply(test_data, myfun))
colnames(df) <- c(LETTERS[1:5])

        # A       B       C       D       E
# 1 -0.2372  0.5900  0.3196 -1.2442 ST 123E
# 2  0.5231  0.7619  0.5639  0.2814   LD 34
# 3  0.0390  1.7421 -0.2890 -0.9240 ST 123E
# 4  1.6180 -0.8037 -0.0822  0.9123 ST 123E
# 5 -1.0774  0.7327  0.1760 -0.4972 ST 123E

str(df)
# 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 # $ A: num  -0.237 0.523 0.039 1.618 -1.077
 # $ B: num  0.59 0.762 1.742 -0.804 0.733
 # $ C: num  0.3196 0.5639 -0.289 -0.0822 0.176
 # $ D: num  -1.244 0.281 -0.924 0.912 -0.497
 # $ E: Factor w/ 2 levels "LD 34","ST 123E": 2 1 2 2 2
```